# HTML, Javascript, Node, Fetch get, "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fetch

I recently got into some trouble thinking that I was using the fetch api correctly. For some context, after the index markup building it calls a fetch to the api running on domain that has cross origin configured. This is the script included in the html to fetch:

```
fetch(`${document.location.origin}:3000/api/cred`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

this is where it's fetching to:

```
app.get('/api/cred', (req,res) => {
    
    console.log('cred began');
   const rawSkey = fs.readFileSync('secret.json'); 
   var skey;
   
   console.log('skey read');
   if(rawSkey.start == "null")
   {
       console.log('skey is null');
        skey  = null;
        
        this.wallet(skey);
        res.json('skey is null');
        return;
   }
   console.log('skey is ');
   
        skey = Buffer.from(rawSkey, 'hex');
   
   this.wallet(skey);
   
   res.json('skey is not null'); 
});
```

as you can see, there are some debug strings that don't end up printing to console since it doesn't connect to begin with to that endpoint.

this is the relevant console messages:

```
boot.js:1 GET https://goldengates.club:3000/api/cred net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(anonymous) @ boot.js:1
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ boot.js:3
```

what is it am I doing wrong, and how?

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` means that there isn't anything listening on `goldengates.club:3000`. If you're self-hosting, make sure you're binding to `0.0.0.0` (`app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', ...)`) and that a firewall isn't blocking the port 3000.

Comment: Ok I will check to see if the port might be blocked by a fire wall